# mysql trigger not recognized

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

im trying to create an `After Insert` trigger but when i run it, it gives no errors but mySQL server seems to ignore it.

When i inscpect the table after i create the trigger, the trigger section remains empty. Here is the code:

```
delimiter $$

    CREATE TRIGGER t_calcula_preco AFTER INSERT ON produto

    begin

    declare id = last_insert_id();

    declare tipo_id;

    declare iva;

    declare valor_iva;

    declare preco_sem_iva;

    -- guardamos o ID do tipo de jogo
    select new.prod_tdj_id into tipo_id from produto where new.prod_id = id;

    -- guardamos o ID do iva
    select tdj_iva_id into iva from tipo_de_jogo where tdj_id = tipo_id;

    -- guardamos o valor do IVA
    select valor into valor_iva from iva where iva_id = iva;

    -- guardamos o valor do preco sem iva
    select new.prod_preco into preco_sem_iva from produto where new.prod_id = id;

    -- agora calculamos o preco com iva

     update produto set prod_preco = (preco_sem_iva + (preco_sem_iva * valor_iva / 100));
    end ;

    delimiter ;
```

any ideas ?

What i want to achieve is : After i insert a row into table "Produto" I want to update one of those values according to another value in another table.

EDIT :
i tried running the code multiple times, it seems it doenst even create the trigger or else it would give me an error "Trigger already exists"

Comment: Try refreshing your client. BTW what is the trigger section of the table?

Comment: it's when i do "Inspect Table" on mySQL server and it has sections for the Columns, Store Procedures, Triggers etc, the Triggers one is empty even after i run the create trigger code.

Comment: i tried running the code multiple times, it seems it doenst even create the trigger or else it would give me an error "Trigger already exists"

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would update the price of _all_ products in the table after an update to use the vat rate of the newly inserted product. I don't think that is what you intended, you're missing a where clause in the update statement. Also, there should be a "$$" somewhere before you try to change back the delimiter to end the create trigger statement.

Comment: No i just want to update the last inserted value, thats why i use the last_insert_id.

Comment: when i use $$ on the End statement, it says that begin is not in a valid position

Comment: You cannot update the contents of the table your trigger is on.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my initial comment, you cannot update the contents of the table your trigger is on (aside from the row the trigger is operating on); and it is generally not a good idea to select from it either. Also, as others implied, you did not actually terminate your trigger definition (with the substitute $$ delimiter). Additionally, you seemed to be a bit confused on use of `NEW`.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER t_calcula_preco AFTER INSERT ON produto

BEGIN

   DECLARE iva;
   DECLARE valor_iva;

   -- guardamos o ID do iva
   SELECT tdj_iva_id INTO iva 
   FROM tipo_de_jogo 
   WHERE tdj_id = NEW.prod_tdj_id
   ;

   -- guardamos o valor do IVA
   SELECT valor INTO valor_iva 
   FROM iva 
   WHERE iva_id = iva
   ;

   -- agora calculamos o preco com iva
   SET NEW.prod_preco := (NEW.prod_preco + (NEW.prod_preco * valor_iva / 100))
   ;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

*Edit: removed final `UPDATE` that I had accidentally left included from the initial copy-paste; and upper-cased all SQL keywords for readability.*

**Note: iva and valor_iva should have data types in their declarations.**